# How can I store this classes inside MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that will send values to an api then insert this values inside a MySQL database, speaking about structure, what is the best way to store this values there, keeping in mind to make it easy when I'll need to retrieve the data and covert to the models?

```
class Show {

  String id;
  String cover;
  String title;
  String desc;
  List<Season> seasons;
  String year;
  String thumbnail;

}

class Season {

  String cover;
  List<Episode> episodes;

}

class Episode {

  String url;

}
```

Comment: In a normal relational database design, you'd likely need 3 tables, one for each class, with foreign keys between them. If you're not familiar with relational database design, you really need to study the topic a bit before trying to create a database design of your own, otherwise you are quite likely to make some problematic mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the classes and properties each one has your database model in MySQL should look like:

```
create table `show` (
  id int primary key not null,
  cover varchar(200) not null,
  title varchar(200) not null,
  `desc` varchar(200) not null,
  year int not null,
  thumbnail varchar(200) not null
);

create table season (
  id int primary key not null auto_increment,
  cover varchar(200) not null,
  show_id int not null references `show` (id)
);

create table episode (
  id int primary key not null auto_increment,
  url varchar(200) not null,
  season_id int not null references season (id)
);
```

With this structure you can store, retrieve, and update all the information of those clases. Some column will need some tweak since I doubt a thumbnail will fit in 200 chars.

Comment: thumnail will be a short url. When I insert into table "show", the foreign keys (show_id and season_id) will be inserted automatically? I don't know about these values , how they will get it's values from the other table.

Comment: When you insert a show you get its autogenerated `id`. Anyway it doesn't have any season, or episode yet, so there aren't any foreign keys involved. When you insert a season, you need to use the `id` you got before, but this happens later in time.

Comment: I didn't understand how show_id (season table) and  season_id (episode table) will get his values or if I will need to add them manually when inserting data on  his tables.

Comment: 1) You insert a show, and you automatically get a new `id` for the show. 2) You insert a season, while manually providing the previous id as `show_id`; and... you now automatically get a new `id` for the season just created. 3) You insert an episode, while manually providing the previous id as `season_id`; and... you automatically get a new `id` for the episode you just created. Rinse and repeat.